# iPhone Dev. Apps: "Promo Codes" button in iTunes is missing

Tags: iphone

I have got a few apps in my iTunes Developer Backend. 
Since yesterday the "Promo Code" button is missing in some of my apps details view. The rest of my apps have still this button and I can download promocodes. Does any one know this problem and maybe solved it?

Thx :-)

Comment: just a guess but maybe you have requested your 50 codes already?

Comment: no, there are some new apps without that button. and some of my other apps have the button, but do not have any codes.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem. There is no Request Promo Codes link anywhere on my iTunes Connect admin. I've only requested 5 codes so far and I have all of the email receipts for them, but now I can't seem to access that area anymore. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: It seems today is hide-and-seek-button-day. From times to times Apple changes buttons from one place to another, sometimes forgetting to enable them at the end of the day. Last week it was the Hold for Developer Release and previous week the Reject this Binary, that now is hidden on binary. Just fill a bug report (bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @koregan - yeah that's were I would expect it, but no. I only see the manage localizations button and nothing else in that column. :-(

Answer (score 2):

> Thank you for contacting Apple
>   Developer Support with regard to
>   iTunes Connect Promo Codes. Please
>   know that applications which are rated
>   17+ will not be provided Promotional
>   Codes for distribution. As such, the
>   usual button to request Promo Codes in
>   iTunes Connect will not be visible for
>   these applications on the Version
>   Details page.

If one controls what you ship, is it censorship or dictatorship?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking under the currently shipping version? should be alongside the `Manage Localizations`

They did move around in the update to iTunesConnect a few months back.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem so I emailed Apple.  Here is their reply:

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Support with regard to iTunes Connect Promo Codes. Please know that applications which are rated 17+ will not be provided Promotional Codes for distribution. As such, the usual button to request Promo Codes in iTunes Connect will not be visible for these applications on the Version Details page.

That solved the mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app rated 17+ ?
Apple recently turn off promo codes for applications rated 17+.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still looking, I found the Promo Codes button under the Features tab NOT the App Store tab of the app details page in iTunes Connect.